# 4-bit adder not adding correctly

Tags: verilog, modelsim, quartus

I'm creating a 4-bit adder using 1-bit adder in Verilog and facing a problem that my 4-bit is not adding correctly.

This is my code for both:

1bit

```
   module ab_fulladd (A,B,Cin,S,Cout);
output Cout,S;
input A,B,Cin;
wire w1,w2,w3;
xor G1(S,A,B,Cin);
and
 G2(w1,A,B),
 G3(w2,A,Cin),
 G4(w3,B,Cin);
or
 G5(Cout,w1,w2,w3);
endmodule
```

4-bit

```
    module add4bit_parametric (a, b, cin, cout, sum);  

parameter size = 4;  

input [size-1:0] a, b; 
input cin;  
output cout;  
output [size-1:0] sum;  
wire [size-2:0] c; 

 genvar i;  

generate  

for (i = 0; i < size; i = i + 1) begin: adder 

if (i == 0)  

      ab_fulladd fa (a[i], b[i], cin, c[i], sum[i]);  

else if (i == size-1)  

     ab_fulladd  fa(a[i],b[i],c[i-1],cout,sum[i]);  

else  

    ab_fulladd fa (a[i],b[i],c[i-1],c[i],sum[i]);  

end endgenerate  

endmodule
```

My 4-bit is not adding up well in the waveform.  Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You have a port connection bug.  You mistakenly connected the `sum` and `c` signals because you use connection-by-order.  To avoid this common type of mistake, use connection-by-name.  Change:

```
ab_fulladd fa (a[i], b[i], cin, c[i], sum[i]);
```

to:

```
ab_fulladd fa (.A(a[i]), .B(b[i]), .Cin(cin), .Cout(c[i]), .S(sum[i]));
```

Repeat this for all instances.  Here is the complete module code:

```
module add4bit_parametric (a, b, cin, cout, sum);  

parameter size = 4;  

input [size-1:0] a, b; 
input cin;  
output cout;  
output [size-1:0] sum;  
wire [size-2:0] c; 

 genvar i;  

generate  

for (i = 0; i < size; i = i + 1) begin: adder 

if (i == 0)  

      ab_fulladd fa (.A(a[i]), .B(b[i]), .Cin(cin), .Cout(c[i]), .S(sum[i]));

else if (i == size-1)  

     ab_fulladd  fa(.A(a[i]), .B(b[i]), .Cin(c[i-1]), .Cout(cout), .S(sum[i]));

else  

    ab_fulladd fa (.A(a[i]), .B(b[i]), .Cin(c[i-1]), .Cout(c[i]), .S(sum[i]));

end endgenerate  

endmodule
```

It compiles on multiple simulators on [edaplayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/E9rF) (sign up for a free account).